# Reasoning behind the u8, u, and U string literals

Tags: c++, c++11

What was the reasoning behind string literals `u8`, `u` and `U`? Why were these specific literals picked? To me something like `u8`, `u16` and `u32` would be clearer at first glance at the code.

Does someone have any links to discussions about this?

Comment: Doesn't have [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) enough information? Or would you like to discuss why it was made like that with us? Or even worse asking for 3rd party resources of such discussions?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I know what each of them means. I'm asking if someone knows **why** they were used.

Comment: Ask the standards commitee then. Looks your question is off-topic.

Comment: You'd have to read the proposals - I'd start here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2209.html. At least the u and U suffixes come from C, so you'd need to look at the discussion there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letters `u` and `U` were chosen because they were also proposed in a [C language Technical report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1040.pdf).

The `u8` was added later, when UTF-8 support was also seen as needed. At that times it was too late to change the other two.